# Does Dissipative system have point Koopman spectrum or continuous Koopman spectrum?

Tags: spectral-theory, koopman-operator

I am studying the Koopman operator and its spectrum. Koopman spectrum is a new topic for me and It is hard to understand what kind of dynamical system shows the point spectrum and what does not.
what are the dynamical systems with point Koopman spectrum? does a dissipative system or more specifically the damped pendulum show the point Koopman spectrum?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.